# MacVim: create new file from command line by using `alias mvim="open -a macvim"`

Tags: command-line, macvim, createfile

When I use `vim newfilename` to open a file and this file does not exit, `vim` will create a new file with the name `newfilename`.

However, `MacVim` does not work in this way --- i.e. `mvim newfilename` (`alias mvim="open -a macvim"`) will lead to an error: `newfilename does not exist`

Is there a way to configure `MacVim` such that `mvim newfilename` (`alias mvim="open -a macvim"`) will create a new file and open it?

Comment: I'm running mvim version 7.3.237 and it creates new files just fine.  What version are you running?

Comment: @peter-lyons: that's weird, I have the same version. I download the `macvim` binary from the official website, rather than compiling the source code. Is that the problem?

Comment: I got snapshot 58 from here (I'm running Janus).  Maybe try that?  https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/downloads  Otherwise, it's easy to alias mvim in your shell to a little shell function that uses `touch` to make a file if it doesn't already exist and then launch mvim on it.

Comment: @peter-lyons: Thanks a lot for the information. I just realised that I am using `alias mvim="open -a macvim"` rather the official `mvim` script. The official `mvim` script works quite well to create new files, but has problems to open a file in an existing `MacVim` window. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478755/macvim-open-file-in-existing-window

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Thanks for the link to that question, which links to a mailing list discussion with a good solution to the new window problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing the error message comes from `open`, not from `vim`. You can replace your alias with a function;

```
mvim () {
    local f
    for f; do
        test -e "$f" || touch "$f"
    done
    open -a macvim "$@"
}
```

This will create empty files if necessary before opening them.

**edit** Didn't see @Peter Lyons' comment about this; credit should go to him for first suggesting this solution. I'll be happy to remove this answer if Peter wants to submit his.

Comment: It works very well, thank you very much!!! @Peter Lyons: thank you very much too!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the mvim alias to the open command, you can instead use the [mvim launcher script](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/src/MacVim/mvim) that comes bundled with most MacVim Snaphots. After adding that mvim to your path, then runing `mvim newfile`, will now open a newfile buffer in an new MacVim window just like gvim would.

**The MacVim mvim script as linked to above:**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This shell script passes all its arguments to the binary inside the
# MacVim.app application bundle.  If you make links to this script as view,
# gvim, etc., then it will peek at the name used to call it and set options
# appropriately.
#
# Based on a script by Wout Mertens and suggestions from Laurent Bihanic.  This
# version is the fault of Benji Fisher, 16 May 2005 (with modifications by Nico
# Weber and Bjorn Winckler, Aug 13 2007).
# First, check "All the Usual Suspects" for the location of the Vim.app bundle.
# You can short-circuit this by setting the VIM_APP_DIR environment variable
# or by un-commenting and editing the following line:
# VIM_APP_DIR=/Applications

if [ -z "$VIM_APP_DIR" ]
then
    myDir="`dirname "$0"`"
    myAppDir="$myDir/../Applications"
    for i in ~/Applications ~/Applications/vim $myDir $myDir/vim $myAppDir $myAppDir/vim /Applications /Applications/vim /Applications/Utilities /Applications/Utilities/vim; do
        if [ -x "$i/MacVim.app" ]; then
            VIM_APP_DIR="$i"
            break
        fi
    done
fi
if [ -z "$VIM_APP_DIR" ]
then
    echo "Sorry, cannot find MacVim.app.  Try setting the VIM_APP_DIR environment variable to the directory containing MacVim.app."
    exit 1
fi
binary="$VIM_APP_DIR/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim"

# Next, peek at the name used to invoke this script, and set options
# accordingly.

name="`basename "$0"`"
gui=
opts=

# GUI mode, implies forking
case "$name" in m*|g*|rm*|rg*) gui=true ;; esac

# Restricted mode
case "$name" in r*) opts="$opts -Z";; esac

# vimdiff, view, and ex mode
case "$name" in
    *vimdiff)
        opts="$opts -dO"
        ;;
    *view)
        opts="$opts -R"
        ;;
    *ex)
        opts="$opts -e"
        ;;
esac

# Last step:  fire up vim.
# The program should fork by default when started in GUI mode, but it does
# not; we work around this when this script is invoked as "gvim" or "rgview"
# etc., but not when it is invoked as "vim -g".
if [ "$gui" ]; then
    # Note: this isn't perfect, because any error output goes to the
    # terminal instead of the console log.
    # But if you use open instead, you will need to fully qualify the
    # path names for any filenames you specify, which is hard.
    exec "$binary" -g $opts ${1:+"$@"}
else
    exec "$binary" $opts ${1:+"$@"}
fi
```